# CodeAbbey Challenge 14 data entry issues?

Tags: java, import

```
    int fnum = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);// holds 5
    //split[] holds each line of the file.
    double sum = fnum;// sum = 5
    double i = 0.0;
    double last = 0.0;



    for(int j = 1; j<(split.length-1);j++)
    {
        i = Integer.parseInt(split[j].replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));

            if(split[j].charAt(0) == '*')
            {
                sum = sum * i;
            }
            else if(split[j].charAt(0) == '/')
            {
                sum = sum / i;

            }
            else if(split[j].charAt(0) == '+')
            {
                sum = sum + i;

            }
            else if(split[j].charAt(0) == '-')
            {
                sum = sum - i;

            }
            else if(split[j].charAt(0) == '%')
            {
                sum = sum % i;

            }

    }
        System.out.println(sum);// Prints 1.0       
    }
}
/*
 Actual Data File Imported

5
+ 3
* 7
+ 10
* 2
* 3
+ 1
% 11
Answer should be : 1 
*/
```

Alright My code may look messy, but I tried hard on it. Gave up a few times but tried again. My question is for smaller data sets such as the one I imported and commented out on the code on the last few lines, work fine. But for bigger data sets it's all wrong why is that? I've tried making al my data sets double to get bigger values but somehow it's wrong?
I'm a beginner so far, any help would be greatly appreciated.
To be more specific on the problem I imported the file, I made it all a String, line by line, then I added it all in a String array so each line was in a string array for example split[1] would print + 3. Now after that I isolated the number and the symbol in the if loop wrapped in a forloop to go over all the sets. Now the if loop captures the symbols and then does the appropriate arithmetic. SomeHow it didn't though? And I used a double instead of an int for sum. That didn't help.I believe the if statement could be the issue.

Comment: I think you should look to better isolate the problem bearing in mind this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I made it more specific, Narrowed the problem to the for-loop

Comment: This is not exactly what he had in mind - mcve :)

Comment: Alright, deleted unnecessary part of the code and only posted the part where I seem to have trouble with. I hope that makes it minimal and complete

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need the answer but, here's a tip:
The whole point of that specific exercise was to learn the modular arithmetic, which is that if you sum up/multiply the remainders of all of the numbers, you get the same answer as you would using the numbers given, that is if you apply the same number that's after % for all of them.
For example:

```
14
+ 78
* 9
* 3
+ 4
% 3
```

After all of the applied operations, the numbers above % 3 result in 2488.
And so 2488 % 3 = 1.

So if you apply % 3 to each one of the numbers, including the initial one, you get the same answer, using the same operations on their remainders of course and dividing the sum again by 3.

```
14 % 3 = 2
78 % 3 = 0
9 % 3 = 0
3 % 3 = 0
4 % 3 = 1
```

So, you get `2 + 0 * 0 * 0 + 1` which equals to 1.
And `1 % 3 = 1` which is the same as `2488 % 3 = 1`.

My point being, you should apply modulo to every one of the numbers, so you get little numbers and don't even have the big ones you're having problems with.
Hope this was clear enough and hope it helps.

Comment: That was a big help Thank you, went and redid that problem. Understood it better that 15th time around